# How to save a file when a button is clicked on email in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, mail-server

I send a user email using Java spring boot with a approve and decline button. If the approve button is clicked a certain file must be saved and the time log should be noted and if declined the file must be deleted. If neither approved nor declined under a certain time frame it should be deleted.

I am aware of sending these mails and buttons but I am not able to trigger the file save or delete action when approve is clicked from mail.

Comment: When you posta  a question, It would be usefull If you post more information. Code which creates the email, code of the email itself (html?), what actions are really under those buttons (html links?).

Answer (score 0):

You could just embed the URL which sends a request to your server and open that URL in a new browser tab. On the frontend side, you can write an HTML code something like:

```
<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/approve?emailId=1234" target="_blank">Approve</a>
<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/decline?emailId=1234" target="_blank">Decline</a>
```

**If neither approved nor declined under a certain time frame it should be deleted. ->**
You can use a scheduled job on your serverside which checks every file one by one in an interval. If you don't know how to do it you can follow the following tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks